# Debug Print Macro in C?

Tags: c, macros

in C, what is the proper way to define a printf like macro that will print only when DEBUG symbol is defined?

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG_PRINT(???) ???
#else
#define DEBUG_PRINT(???) ???
#endif
```

where ??? is where I am not sure what to fill in

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing among many others.

Comment: has been asked before; link to my answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing/1645152#1645152

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C #define macro for debug printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing)

Answer (score 47):

I've seen this idiom a fair amount:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
# define DEBUG_PRINT(x) printf x
#else
# define DEBUG_PRINT(x) do {} while (0)
#endif
```

Use it like:

```
DEBUG_PRINT(("var1: %d; var2: %d; str: %s\n", var1, var2, str));
```

The extra parentheses are necessary, because some older C compilers don't support var-args in macros.

Comment: Thanks for the annotation about  the extra parentheses.

Comment: I see some minor errors in your implementation (missing parenthesis around `x`, for instance, and not using `__VA_ARGS__`). [So, here is my approach, based on yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67667132/4561887).

Comment: @GabrielStaples This answer intends to explain very old code, that predates the `__VA_ARGS__` based approach. In code less than 20 years old, you should certainly prefer `__VA_ARGS__`.

Answer (score 31):

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG_PRINT(...) do{ fprintf( stderr, __VA_ARGS__ ); } while( false )
#else
#define DEBUG_PRINT(...) do{ } while ( false )
#endif
```

Comment: +1 for `__VA_ARGS__`, but note that's only required to exist in C99 implementations.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the `do { ... } while (0)` idiom around the `fprintf()`

Comment: For the record, you need to be using C99 for __VA_ARGS__ to work. Use -std-c99 in you CFLAGS

Answer (score 23):

Thank you mipadi, I improved your DEBUG_PRINT with file information too.

```
#define DEBUG 3

#if defined(DEBUG) && DEBUG > 0
 #define DEBUG_PRINT(fmt, args...) fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG: %s:%d:%s(): " fmt, \
    __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, ##args)
#else
 #define DEBUG_PRINT(fmt, args...) /* Don't do anything in release builds */
#endif
```

Tested with latest clang, e.g.

```
int main(int argc, char **args) {
    DEBUG_PRINT("Debugging is enabled.\n");    
    DEBUG_PRINT("Debug level: %d", (int) DEBUG);
}
```

outputs:

```
DEBUG: debug.c:13:main(): Debugging is enabled.
DEBUG: debug.c:14:main(): Debug level: 3
```

Answer (score 22):

Something like:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG_PRINT(fmt, args...)    fprintf(stderr, fmt, ## args)
#else
#define DEBUG_PRINT(fmt, args...)    /* Don't do anything in release builds */
#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

Use different signatures of DEBUG_PRINT, they don't have to be the same, like:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG_PRINT printf
#else
#define DEBUG_PRINT(...)
#endif
```

this way on debug mode the DEBUG_PRINT call will be replaced with printf. On release it will ignore all arguments used previously.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define DEBUG_PRINT printf
#else
    #define DEBUG_PRINT
#endif
```

Comment: if you have code like this 
`if(x) 
 DEBUG_PRINT("SOME DEBUG");` then this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

**This works in both C and C++!** (Note that the space before `__VA_ARGS__` is *required* for it to work in C++!)

I see some minor errors in [the implementation in the main answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1941337/4561887). So, here is my approach:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define DEBUG_PRINTF(...) printf("DEBUG: " __VA_ARGS__)
#else
    #define DEBUG_PRINTF(...) do {} while (0)
#endif
```

Example usage:

```
DEBUG_PRINTF("hello\n");
```

Then, if I build and run with the `-DDEBUG` define on in my C build options, like this:

```
# Build
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c11 -DDEBUG -o build/my_program \
my_program_tests.c my_program.c

# Run
build/my_program
```

then I see this output:

> ```
> DEBUG: hello
> ```

But if I build withOUT the `-DDEBUG` define in my compiler C options, then I see no debug prints whatsoever.

### Other references

1. The fix to make this compatible with C++ too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72777133/4561887: add a space before `__VA_ARGS__`. Use `"DEBUG: " __VA_ARGS__` instead of `"DEBUG: "__VA_ARGS__`!

Answer (score 0):

I like this way the best because it wont add any asm instructions to your release build.

```
#define DEBUG
#ifdef DEBUG
#define  debug_printf(fmt, ...)  printf(fmt, __VA_ARGS__);
#else
#define debug_printf(fmt, ...)    /* Do nothing */
#endif
```