# Valgrind on FreeBSD

Tags: valgrind, freebsd, raspberry-pi2

Good day!

I'm playing around one C project. It is located on FreeBSD machine (it looks like Raspberry PI2, not sure)

[image]

The problem is I want to run project in Valgrind to find memory leakage. When I try to install Valgrind through ports, I get next error:

```
root@raspberry-2-55:/usr/ports/devel/valgrind # make
===>  valgrind-3.10.1.20160113,1 is only for i386 amd64, while you are running
armv6.
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/ports/devel/valgrind
```

Please help to run valgrind on this platform.

Answer (score 6):

The combination ARM6/FreeBSD is not supported.

Valgrind [fully supports FreeBSD i386 and amd64](http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html). You can find information on the ports here [FreeBSD stable port](http://www.freshports.org/devel/valgrind/) and here [FreeBSD development port](http://www.freshports.org/devel/valgrind-devel/).

At a guess, Valgrind support for ARM won't be implemented until and if ARM becomes a Tier 1 platform or until someone steps forward to do the porting.

See also the Valgrind team's statement on porting:

> Maintaining each port takes a lot of effort, more so than for most other programs. Valgrind is fragile due to the low-level nature of what it does. Also, each platform port has CPU-specific code, OS-specific code and platform-specific code, and testing all the combinations is difficult.

**Update:**

On FreeBSD you can use the very powerful [`dtrace`](https://wiki.freebsd.org/DTrace/Tutorial) tool for performance monitoring and debugging. It does have a steep learning curve, though.

My favorite debugging tool is still placing `printf()` in strategic locations. Say you suspect your program crashes in a large block of code. Place a `printf` in the middle, recompile and re-run. If you see the output, the error came after the `printf`. If you don't it was before the `printf`. You have now halved the size of the block containing the error. Now add another `printf` in the middle of the remaining suspicious code and repeat. This technique is called bisection. You can also use it to monitor the value of a variable.

I would suggest to wrap the debugging `printf` in a macro ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941307/c-debug-print-macros)), so you can leave them in the code but you can disable them for a release build.

Comment: Great thanks for your answer. So what options are there to debug programs written in C language (except for `gdb`) on FreeBSD/ARM?