# Variadic macros with 0 arguments in C99

Tags: macros, c99, variadic

I have some debugging code that looks like the following:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)
#define AT __FILE__ ":" TOSTRING(__LINE__)
void __my_error(const char*loc, const char *fmt, ...);
#define my_error(fmt, ...) __my_error(AT, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

The last macro is used so I can insert the location into the debug output as to where the error occurred. However, when I call the function like this:

```
my_error("Uh oh!");
```

I would *like* my code to be C99, so I find when this compiles, I get the following error:

```
error: ISO C99 requires rest arguments to be used
```

I know I can solve this by changing the call to

```
my_error("Uh oh!", NULL);
```

But is there any way to make this look less ugly? Thanks!

Comment: Also you might want to have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing (the Single argument section)

Comment: Beware when defining your own names with two adjacent underscores in them: all such names are reserved by the standard (so a library, compiler, or standard update might use them in some way).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I see two solutions to this problem. (Three if you count 'stick with gcc').

#### Extra special case macro

Add a new macro for when you want to print a fixed string.

```
#define my_errorf(str) my_error(str, NULL)
```

*Pro*: Minimum amount of extra code.
*Con:* It's easy to use the wrong macro (but at least you notice this at compile time).

#### Put `fmt` inside the '...'

Vararg macro's can have only __VA_ARGS__ as parameter (unlike vararg functions). So you can put the `fmt` argument inside the __VA_ARGS__ and change your function.

```
void __my_error(const char *loc, ...);
#define my_error(...) __my_error(AT, __VA_ARGS__)
```

*Pro*: One syntax/macro for all error messages.
*Con*: Requires rewriting of your `__my_error` function, which might not be possible.

Comment: Yes, the two functions are the same (typo on my part). I'll give solution number 2 a try and see if I can sort that out.

What do you suggest for naming conventions for things which are essentially private (such as the `__my_error` function, which should never be called directly)?

Comment: @Michael Let me know how it works out. I usually add a '_suffix' to the macro name like `my_error_real`, `my_error_private` or just `my_error_x` (from 'eXpanded').

Comment: Vararg macros *can* have more than just __VA_ARGS__ as a parameter.  You could, for example, pass a FILE* (for fprintf) or a char[] (for snprintf).  It's just that the ... must match at least one argument, at least in gcc's interpretation of C99.

Comment: Those are workarounds, not a way to disable the warning :(

Comment: Putting `fmt` inside `...` will prevent you from prepending and appending to the format string.

Comment: Why does the second option requre rewriting the function? The macro expansion is just textual, it doesn't care if the first argument from `__VA_ARGS__` lines up with the first `...` of the function, right? So is there some other reason I'm missing?