# C/C++ How to expand a macro parameter into text between quotes

Tags: c++, c, macros

Here is what I have (message() is a specialized logging function from a third party library):

```
#define LOG(fmt, ...) message("%s %s(): #fmt", __FILE__, __func__, __VA_ARGS__);
```

So I want to be able to do things like:

```
LOG("Hello world")
LOG("Count = %d", count)
```

And have it expand to:

```
message("%s %s(): Hello world", __FILE__, __func__);
message("%s %s(): Count = %d", __FILE__, __func__, count);
```

But the #fmt thing is not working. It does not evaluate to the macro argument and prints as "#fmt". Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't put `#fmt` in the quotes. Just use [string literal concatenation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#String_literal_concatenation) to join the two literals.

```
#define LOG(fmt, ...) message("%s %s(): " fmt, __FILE__, __func__, __VA_ARGS__);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but actually for an unrelated reason my first example doesn't work (LOG("Hello world") i.e. not using any parameter). However there is already good discussion on that topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576396/variadic-macros-with-0-arguments-in-c99