# How to overload printf or cout

Tags: c++, debugging, function

I use cout statements in my program for debugging purposes. I would like to make a function that works like it, or works like printf, but is sensitive to a global variable. If this global variable is true, then it will print to screen. If it is false, then it won't print anything. Is there already a function like this? If not, then how can it be made?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Macro to turn off printf statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765175/macro-to-turn-off-printf-statements)

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
int myPrintf(const char* format, ...) 
{
  if (globalCheck == 0)
    return 0
  va_list vl;
  va_start(vl, format);
  auto ret = vprintf(format, vl);
  va_end(vl);
  return ret;
}
```

`va_start` and `va_end` take the arguments in the `...` and encapsulate them in a `va_list`. with this `va_list` you can then the `vprintf` which is a variant of `printf` designed exactly for this need.

Side note - usually it is bad practice to use global variables. A better thing to do is to encapsulate it in a class like this -

```
class ConditionalPrinter {
public:
  ConditionalPrinter() : m_enable(true) {}
  void setOut(bool enable) { m_enable = enable; }
  int myPrintf(const char* format, ...);
private:
  bool m_enable;
}
```

and then to check m_enable instead of the global variable.
Usage of this looks like this:

```
ConditionalPrinter p;
p.myPrintf("hello %d", 1);   // printed
p.setOut(false);
p.myPrintf("hello2 %d", 1);  // not printed
```

....

Answer (score 3):

Don't write it yourself. Doing it right is **much** harder then you think. Even harder when you need threads and efficiency. Use one of existing logging libraries like:

- glog: https://github.com/google/glog (I prefer this - it is lightweight and do what it needs to do)
- Log4cpp http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/ (powerful and configuration compatible with popular java logging)
- ... add your favorite to this wiki

Answer (score 2):

As someone else said, there are several good logging frameworks available. However, if you want to roll your own, the first thing to note is that cout isn't a function, it's a stream. The function is `operator<<`. What you can do is something like the following:

```
/* trace.h */
extern ostream debug;

void trace_init();
void trace_done();

/* trace.cpp */
#include "trace.h"
ostream debug(cout.rdbuf());
static ofstream null;

void trace_init()
{
    null.open("/dev/null");
    if(output_is_disabled) {  // put whatever your condition is here
        debug.rdbuf(null.rdbuf());
    }
}

void trace_done()
{
    null.close();
}
```

You might have to adjust a bit if you're on a platform without `/dev/null`. What this does is let you write

```
debug << "here's some output << endl;
```

and if you have the output enabled, it will write to cout. If not, it will write to `/dev/null` where you won't see anything.

For that matter, you could just set cout's rdbuf to somewhere where you won't see that output, but I would find that to be a really bad idea. Creating new streams gives you a lot more flexibility in controlling your output.