# What is this (( ))?

Tags: c++, c

While browsing through the gcc compiler source code (gcc/c-family/c-pragma.c) I see:

```
typedef struct GTY(()) align_stack {
  int                  alignment;
  tree                 id;
  struct align_stack * prev;
} align_stack;
```

and regardless of having lots of C programming years behind me, these bits: `(())` are totally unknown to me yet. Can someone please explain what they mean? Google does not seem to find it.

Comment: And what is this `GTY`? It's not defined in the language standard. See your code.

Comment: is GTY a macro???

Comment: You can find it on Google by specifying site in query string as follows:`GTY site:gcc.gnu.org`

Answer (score 82, accepted):

They are GCC internal "magic", i.e. part of the compiler implementation itself.

See [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Type-Information.html) which talks about their use. The macro is used to mark types for garbage-collection purposes. There can be arguments too, see [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GTY-Options.html#GTY-Options) for details.

**UPDATE**:: As pointed out by [Drew Dorman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16287/drew-dormann) in a comment, the actual double parenthesis are not part of the "internalness" of the GNU implementation; they're commonly used when you want to collect an entire list of arguments into a single argument for the called macro. This can be useful sometimes when wrapping e.g. `printf()`, too. [See this question, for more on this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765175/macro-to-turn-off-printf-statements).

Comment: @Krishnabhadra explanation can be found on the linked site. Further explanation about the GCC features related to the GTY-marker imo would be beyond the scope of this particular question and answer.

Comment: `(())` itself is **not** gcc magic.  It allows an text that includes commas to be passed to a macro as a single argument.  For any C/C++ compiler.

Answer (score 44):

In general, it's used with macros to shield commas. Given `#define foo(a,b)`, the macro invocation `foo(1,2,3)` would be illegal. Using an extra pair of parenthesis clarifies which comma is shielded: `foo((1,2),3)` versus `foo(1,(2,3))`.

In this case, the `GTY` can take multiple arguments, separated by commas, but all these commas must be shielded. That's why the inner `()` surround all arguments.

Comment: Can you explain why somebody should use such a call ?

Comment: E.g. `#define PRINT_A_LOT(a,b) printf("prefix\n"); printf a; printf("infix\n"); printf b; printf("suffix\n");` (In C++ there are nicer solutions than macro's, of course).

Comment: @Albertus: would also be nice, if you pass templates to a macro `Macro((Pair<int, int>), ...)`. Although then you run in additional trouble, getting rid of the parenthesis within the macro