# Error when defining a stringising macro with __VA_ARGS__

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros, stringification

I have been trying to implement a function macro in C that prepends "DEBUG: ", to the argument, and passes its arguments to printf:

```
#define DBG(format, ...) printf("DEBUG: " #format "\n", __VA_ARGS__)
```

This gives me this error in gcc:

```
src/include/debug.h:4:70: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
#define DBG(format, ...) printf("DEBUG: " #format "\n", __VA_ARGS__)
                                                                   ^
```

Supposedly, it should stringise format, and pass its variable arguments to printf, but so far I can't get past this error.

---

**EDIT**

After giving up on stringising arguments, and double-hashing (`##`) `__VA_ARGS__` I now have this error:

```
src/lib/cmdlineutils.c: In function ‘version’:
src/lib/cmdlineutils.c:56:17: warning: ISO C99 requires rest arguments to be used [enabled by default]
  DBG("version()");
```

Should I be placing a comma after the argument?

```
DBG("version()",);  // ?
```

For reference, DBG() now looks like this:

```
#define DBG(format, ...) printf("DEBUG: " format "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: Works for me on gcc, which compiler did you use? Can you try putting a space between the # and format?

Comment: $ gcc --version: gcc (GCC) 4.8.1 20130725 (prerelease)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This happens **unless there's at least one variable argument**. You can try this GNU extension to fix it:

```
#define DBG(format, ...) printf("DEBUG: " #format "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)
                                                        ^^
```

As explained [in the GNU doc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html):

> [if] the variable argument is left out when the macro is used, then
>   the comma before the ‘##’ will be deleted.

Comment: @marcoms Pretty strange, are you sure you copied the line correctly ?

Comment: the only character that is missing from my defenition is the hash (`#`) before `format`, as I decided to stringise the argument when calling it myself, to rule out one possible cause, i.e.: `DBG("printf()");`

Comment: @cnicurar - I'm going to assume those warnings are just the compiler warning me that the double-hashes aren't standard, so you can have an accept

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415.aspx) on MSDN. It contains info on Variadic Macros, which is what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to stringise format, it can stay as is, just treat it as a string when using the macro.

The error, as cnicutar propsed can be solved with adding '##' before the **VA_ARGS**

```
#define DBG(format, ...) printf("DEBUG: " format "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Usage example:

```
DBG("%d - %s", a,b);
```