# C++ Debug Print macro OS X Clang compatible

Tags: c++, macos, clang

I am moving some C++ code to OS X (Maverick) which was previously compiled on Win VC++ 2012 and  Linux GCC 4.7 .I have the following macro to print messages to console in debug mode:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  #define  PrintDebug(msg) Msg::PrintMsg msg
#else
  #define  PrintDebug(msg) (void)0
#endif
```

It worked but in XCode the compiler(clang) spits errors like **"expected ';' after expression"** and **"too many arguments provided to function like macro invocation"**

Important to note,the input to the macro argument has the same format as

```
printf(fmt,...)
```

For example using it with message only:

```
 PrintDebug("Some message\n");
```

throws compile time error:  "expected ';' after expression"

And when I pass the formatting:

```
  PrintDebug("Number:%d\n",someNumber);
```

the error is :too many arguments provided to function like macro invocation

I tried several other variations from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing) but didn't find a match which would work with all 3 compilers.
How do I get it working with CLANG but also be compatible with MSVC and GCC compilers?

Comment: How are you invoking the macro? Looks like it expects to be called like PrintDebug((x,y,z)); not PrintDebug(x,y,z).

Comment: Looks like you need to change `Msg::PrintMsg msg` to `Msg::PrintMsg (msg)`

Comment: Tried that too.It throws "too many arguments provided to function macro invocation"

Comment: What you want is a [variadic macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use variadic macros for this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  #define  PrintDebug(fmt, args...) Msg::PrintMsg (fmt, args)
#else
  #define  PrintDebug(fmt, args...) (void)0
#endif
```