# #define with Variable arguments for debugging

Tags: c, debugging

I have prints available something like this

```
PrintMe(("abc %d",a));
```

Printme defined like this

```
#define Printme(_X_) printf _X_
```

But now i need to map it with some print which takes variable arguments something like

```
#define Printme(format , args ....)   PrintVar(30,format,##args)
```

Printvar has single parentheses and Printme has double parentheses

How to map this

Comment: Is there a reason you're using preprocessor macros instead of a normal function?

Comment: See this post for details on defining debug macros in c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
#define Printme(format, ...)   PrintVar(30, format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Documentation (for GCC): https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

Comment: But Printme has a format like Printme(("abc"));
Printvar is like PrintVar(30, "abc")
since its legacy code i cant change format of Printme

Comment: @Gajanana: OK, I've updated my answer to use the special `##` before `__VA_ARGS__` which makes it work in the case where you have a format string and no additional arguments.

Comment: Problem is Printme ha double Parentheses and PrintVar has single. So its not working –

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#define PRINTME2(fmt, ...) printvar(30, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define PRINTME(_X_) PRINTME2 _X_
```

A complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void printvar(int lvl, char * fmt, ...)
{
    printf("lvl %d:", lvl);                                                                         
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr,fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, argptr);
    va_end(argptr);
}

#define PRINTME2(fmt, ...) printvar(30, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define PRINTME(_X_) PRINTME2 _X_

int main(void)
{
    PRINTME(("I have %u apples\n", 3));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> lvl 30:I have 3 apples