# Unable to call one #define macro from another

Tags: c

I have these lines

```
#define LOG(fp, fmt, ...) fprintf(fp, "%s:%d: "fmt, __FILE__, __LINE__, ## __VA_ARGS__) 
#define OUT(fmt, ...) LOG(stdout, fmt, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Compiler shows OUT to be erroneous. How do I call LOG from within OUT?

Error messages:

1. expected expression before ‘)’ token in LOG
2. expansion error when I use it as `OUT("Hello world");`

Comment: What compiler are you using, and what error message is it giving for what use of `OUT`?

Comment: Error messages 1)expected expression before ‘)’ token in LOG and 2) expansion error when I use it as OUT("Hello world");

Comment: @alk I just got it from the book and it works

Comment: Err .. "*it works*"? Your question states it doesn't.

Comment: @alk LOG itself works without problems. Only when I call it from OUT, that's when the errors appear

Comment: Replace `OUT("Hello world")` with `OUT("%s", "Hello world")`.

Comment: Note the section 'Single Argument C99 Variant' in the [C `#define` macro for debug printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing/1644898#1644898) duplicate. IMO, the other possible duplicate has very limited relevance; it deals with something this question was not attempting to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short explanation because I take from the comments that this was cargo-culted into the code: The `##` in `##__VA_ARGS__` is a **non-standard extension** of the preprocessor (originally from gcc, now also supported by clang). Its effect is that if a variadic macro is called with no variadic parameters, a superfluous preceding comma is removed. That is to say, where

```
#define FOO(bar, ...) foo(bar, __VA_ARGS__)
```

cannot be called with one argument because it would expand to `foo(argument,)`,

```
#define FOO(bar, ...) foo(bar, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

can because the comma is silently removed and the expansion is `foo(argument)`.

Therefore, the solution to your problem is to use

```
//                                     vv--- these are important here
#define OUT(fmt, ...) LOG(stdout, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Otherwise in an expansion of `OUT` with only one argument, the `__VA_ARGS__` in `LOG` will not be empty because it is expanded from

```
LOG(stdout, "Hello, world.",)
```

instead of

```
LOG(stdout, "Hello, world.")
```

...and the `##` before `__VA_ARGS__` in `LOG`  will then have no effect. You get the compiler message because there's an extra comma in the expansion of `LOG` (the `fprintf` call ends with `,)`).

[Link to specifics](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html).

Comment: Cool and so simple! I have just tested it!

Comment: As far as I see my gcc's warnings this approach is not C99 compliant. Using `-pedantic` I get `warning: ISO C99 requires rest arguments to be used [enabled by default]`.

Comment: @alk that is correct. It was originally implemented by gcc, and I just tried with clang 3.5, which also supports it, but I would be surprised if MSVC didn't choke on it. However, MSVC suppresses the trailing comma without `##`, so while confusion is thoroughly achieved, it is possible to hack one's way around the problem with the most common compilers.

Answer (score 0):

The `...` in `OUT(fmt, ..)` implies the need to pass at least one more argument then just `fmt`. Like for example:

```
OUT("%s", "Hello World");
```

If doing so the `##` is useless and the macros should look like:

```
#define LOG(fp, fmt, ...) fprintf((fp), "%s:%d: "fmt, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__) 
#define OUT(fmt, ...) LOG(stdout, fmt, __VA_ARGS__)
```