# C debug macro: error: expected expression

Tags: c, linux, debugging, macros

Every time, I invoke the below C debug macro, I have to pass some argument. Else compilation fails.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define debug(fmt, ...)\
do{\
fprintf(stdout, "%s(%d) : " fmt, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__);\
}while(0)

int
main()
{
    debug("Debug 1");
}
```

Here is the compilation error :

> test.c:12:5: error: expected expression
>           debug("Debug 1");
>       ^ test.c:6:70: note: expanded from macro 'debug'
>           fprintf(stdout, "%s(%d) : " fmt, **FUNCTION**, **LINE**, **VA_ARGS**);\
>                                                                               ^ 1 error generated.

If  I invoke the same macro with an argument :

```
debug("Debug 1 %s", "");
```

It compiles fine with no issues. Is is because of the compiler ? Does it work in latest compiler ?

Comment: BTW please don't tag C questions as [tag:c++]. These are two different languages.

Comment: See [C `#define` macro for debug printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing/1644898#1644898) for a comprehensive discussion of debug printing macros.  Note the sections on 'Single-argument variant' and 'GCC-specific technique' in particular.

Answer (score 2):

[Variadic macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) allow you to pass one or more arguments to a macro in one fell swoop. They do not allow you to pass zero arguments in its place.

Write a second macro that you can use if you do not wish to pass arguments.

> `[C99: 6.10.3/4]:` **If the identifier-list in the macro definition does not end with an ellipsis,** the number of arguments (including those arguments consisting of no preprocessing tokens) in an invocation of a function-like macro shall equal the number of parameters in the macro definition. **Otherwise, there shall be more arguments in the invocation than there are parameters in the macro definition (excluding the `...`)**. There shall exist a `)` preprocessing token that terminates the invocation.

If a different compiler (such as one of those distributed with Microsoft Visual Studio) allows you to pass zero arguments in place of `...`, it is non-compliant. As you can read above, this rule is not implementation-dependant.

Comment: VC++ 14.0 compiles it without a problem. What does the Standard say?

Comment: @Fireho: The same thing I did. N.B. VC++14.0 is not a C compiler, though it's worth noting that C++14 says just the same thing.