# How to write a debug macro to print all the arguments of function (strace style) in C++?

Tags: c++, debugging, macros, variadic-functions

Given any function like

```
void f(int a, int b, char c) {


---macro here----

}
```

now `DBG_ARGS` should have output like
`f(a = 1, b = 2, c = A)`

Can we use `VA_LIST`, `#x` and `__FUNCTION__` to accomplish this?

Comment: Probably not, unless you think `DBG_ARGS(a, b, c)` is ok.

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks. how close can I come to this sort of debug print. Generally while debugging recursive functions, I want to see the arguments being passed and return value being sent. How to solve this problem if not the one mentioned in the question.

Comment: You can look at [C `#define` macro for debug printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/) for a lot of ideas.  It is for C rather than C++, but most of it transfers over.  You need to decide how you'll handle the types. If you handle a fixed number of values of the same type (3 `int`), then it's straight-forward; if you handle a variable number of values of the same type, you have to work harder; if you handle a fixed number of values of different types, you have to work harder again; and if you have a variable number of values of different types, you have to work hardest of all.

Comment: You should probably look at the Boost preprocessor 'library'; it has code that allows you to iterate over the variable length argument list.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with a straight macro alone in the general case, but you could do it using a call to another function.

If you look at the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace) for `backtrace`, you will find a glibc specific routine to dump the stack. If you call another function Y from your current function X, and that function dumps the stack, then the second line of the stack dump will be the arguments to function X (make sure the compiler does not inline the function).

Sadly this method isn't particularly portable. OS-X and Linux have different `backtrace` type implementations, and I'm sure Windows does too.

The `va_list`-esque macros only work with variadic functions. The example you gave is not a variadic function. I'm not exactly aware what `VA_LIST` (upper case) does (perhaps that's compiler specific), but google suggests it's pretty much the same.