# Executing a command from a file(shell)

Tags: c, io, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to make a program that works as mini-shell(Which executes a command written in the terminal). To do so, I'm trying to test of this method works, I created a file where I put the arguments parsed in the terminal, read the file and then parse it to an array to execute using a system call such as execl or execvp..etc. The code I've written so far is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 1024

FILE* ouvrir(char *cmd)
{
    FILE *commandeLog = fopen("commande.txt", "w+");
    if (commandeLog == 0)
    {
        printf("Erreur de création du fichier");
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(commandeLog,"%s", cmd);
    }
    fclose(commandeLog);
    return commandeLog;
}

char** afficher_fichier(FILE *f,char** argv)
{
    f=fopen("commande.txt", "r");
    if (f != NULL)
    {
        char ch;
        while ((ch=fgetc(f))!= EOF)
        {
            printf ("%c",ch);
            **argv=ch;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return argv;
}

void  exec(char **argv)
{
     pid_t  pid;

     if ((pid=fork()) == 0)
     {
          if (execvp(*argv, argv) < 0) 
          {
               printf("*** ERREUR: exec echoué\n");
               exit(1);
          }
     }
     wait(NULL);
}

int  main()
{
    char  cmd[MAX];
    FILE* f=0;
    char** argv=0;
    printf("Entrer -> ");
    fgets(cmd,MAX,stdin);
    int i = strlen(cmd)-1;
    if( cmd[ i ] == '\n') 
        cmd[i] = '\0';
    printf("\n");
    f=ouvrir(cmd);
    afficher_fichier(f,argv);
    exec(argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Upon compiling the code and running, it returns a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" message. The problem is basically in the "afficher_fichier" function.

Is the code I wrote has any logic in it?

If so, how do I correct the error?

If not, how do I reach the goal I seek?

Comment: Make the function `ouvrir()` return a `FILE *`; only ever pass `FILE *` around, never a `FILE`.  A copy of the structure is not guaranteed to 'work' properly.  However, it is puzzling that you don't use the returned value.

Comment: You need to close the file after writing it, and then reopen it for reading. This will ensure that the write data has been written to disk when you do the read.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Look at the last two lines of the main, I masked them as a comment because they generated a segmentation fault.

Comment: You basically do `char **argv = 0; **argv = <some character>;`. See the problem?

Answer (score 1):

#### First pass

Make the function `ouvrir()` return a `FILE *`; only ever pass `FILE *` around, never a `FILE`.  A copy of the structure is not guaranteed to 'work' properly. (The C standard ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.21.3 **Files** says: *The address of the `FILE` object used to control a stream may be significant; a copy of a
`FILE` object need not serve in place of the original.*)  However, it is puzzling that you don't use the returned value.

```
FILE *ouvrir(char *cmd)
{
    FILE *commandeLog = fopen("commande.log", "a");
    if (commandeLog == 0)
    {
        …report error…
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(commandeLog,"%s", cmd);
    }
    return commandeLog;
}
```

Then, in `main()`:

```
FILE *f = 0;    // As now

…

f = ouvrir(cmd);
if (f == 0)
{
    …whatever you need to do that uses f…
    fclose(f);
}
```

If you're later going to read the file without reopening it, then you need to use `"a+"` or a similar mode (`"w+"`, `"r+"` — it depends on whether the `ouvrir()` must create the file, or should use the existing file, and whether all write must be unconditionally at the end of the file).  Alternatively, you can have `ouvrir()` unchanged and arrange to close the file and reopen it for reading (a new function, `reouvrir()`, perhaps).

#### Second pass

After the question was updated, the `afficher_fichier()` file causes most of the problem.  It is currently:

```
char** afficher_fichier(FILE *f,char** argv)
{
    f=fopen("commande.txt", "r");
    if (f != NULL)
    {
        char ch;
        while ((ch=fgetc(f))!= EOF)
        {
            printf ("%c",ch);
            **argv=ch;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return argv;
}
```

Issues include:

1. Why pass in `f` if the first thing you do is overwrite it with a new file stream with `fopen()`.  It should just be a local variable, not an argument.
2. Why pass in `argv` when you are going to return it?
3. The passed in `argv` is a null pointer.  There isn't much point in passing that; you could simply allocate the space in the function.
4. Why are you reading the file at all?  You know it contains the value in `cmd` in `main()`, so why not simply pass that to `afficher_fichier()`?
5. If you pass `cmd` in, you have to decide whether it is OK for the function to mangle the string.  If not, you need to make a copy of the arguments as you find them.
6. With the code as written, you simply copy all characters over the same character in the zeroth argument with no splitting (e.g. on spaces).
7. There's no checking for overflow, but since the memory wasn't allocated, there wasn't really a buffer to overflow, and since it always writes to the same place, maybe it doesn't matter.
8. You don't null terminate the string(s).
9. Your function is passed a null pointer; this does not lead to happiness.
10. Returning the null pointer isn't very helpful.
11. Because you open the file in the function but don't close it, you leak file streams.
12. *…the list could probably continue, but is probably not productive…*

The `exec` function is in decent shape.  It would be better if the error message were printed to `stderr` instead of `stdout`, but otherwise, it'll do — assuming it gets a valid `argv` array of strings passed to it.

Making simplifying assumptions:

- `cmd` is passed to `afficher_fichier()`
- `cmd` can be modified
- spaces separate arguments
- the function doesn't need renaming — even though its current name is no longer appropriate

You might end up with code like:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static
char **afficher_fichier(char *cmd)
{
    printf("-->> [%s]\n", cmd);
    size_t argx = 16;
    size_t argc = 0;
    char **argv = malloc(sizeof(*argv) * argx);
    if (argv == 0)
        return 0;

    char *src = cmd;
    while (*src != '\0')
    {
        while (isspace((unsigned char)*src))
            src++;
        if (*src == '\0')
        {
            printf("<<-- 1\n");
            if (argc == 0)
            {
                free(argv);
                argv = 0;
            }
            else
                argv[argc] = 0;
            return argv;
        }
        if (argc >= argx - 1)
        {
            size_t narg = argx * 2;
            char **argn = realloc(argv, sizeof(*argv) * narg);
            if (argn == 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
                free(argv);
                return 0;
            }
            argv = argn;
            argx = narg;
        }
        argv[argc++] = src;
        while (!isspace((unsigned char)*src))
            src++;
        if (*src != '\0')
            *src++ = '\0';
        printf("%zu = [%s]\n", argc, argv[argc-1]);
    }
    *argv[argc] = 0;
    printf("<<-- 2\n");

    return argv;
}

int main(void)
{
    char cmd[] = "  \tcmd   arg1     arg2 arg3   ";
    char **argv = afficher_fichier(cmd);
    if (argv != 0)
    {
        char **arg = argv;
        while (*arg != 0)
            printf("[%s]\n", *arg++);
    }
    else
        printf("Bother!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
-->> [      cmd   arg1     arg2 arg3   ]
1 = [cmd]
2 = [arg1]
3 = [arg2]
4 = [arg3]
<<-- 1
[cmd]
[arg1]
[arg2]
[arg3]
```

The `printf()` statements with double-headed arrows are diagnostic printing; they'd be omitted from production code (or made into code that prints conditionally if a debugging flag of some sort is set — see [C `#define` macro for debug printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868) for more ideas on that).

Comment: This code partially works, it returns the file correctly and writes it. However, the string is written twice in the file, and the display doesn't show anything.

Comment: You don't really show how the reading code is supposed to work, nor where `exec()` is called, etc.  That makes it a bit hard to see what's going on.  Your entries to the file aren't time-stamped.  I suspect that you ran the program twice and the second line was a result of the second run.  I can't prove that, of course.  As to not reading anything — you don't show the file being opened for reading, as noted in the new paragraph at the end of my answer.   If you open the file for read and write, then you need to rewind (or just `fseek()`) after any write; otherwise, you need to reopen the file.

Comment: Thanks, I realized I haven't opened the file for reading. It works now. And for the exec function, I already stated that you should ignore it as I haven't finished the first steps(writing the file and reading it).

Comment: Also, as a rule, you should create an MCVE ([MCVE]) when you ask a question.  You shouldn't show functions that are not (yet) relevant to your problem.  You also shouldn't update questions by extending them after you've got an answer.  Chameleon questions are not popular.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, I just didn't want to create another question and thought it would be okay to edit it here.