# if statement in macro not work

Tags: c++, c, macros

I am confused about the if statement in macro.
Here is my code:

```
#ifdef SHOW_LOGS_
#define LOG(operation, parameter, value) \
do { \
    if ((parameter) == (NULL)){ \
        fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d: %s\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,operation);\
    }else { \
        fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d: %s, [%s] : %d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,operation,parameter,value);\
    } \
} while(0)
#else
#define LOG 
#endif
```

But, when I test my code like:

```
LOG("ROUNDING UP...",NULL,NULL);
```

The compiler gave me a warning, which tells me that the test code above turn to execute

```
fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d: %s\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,operation);
```

not the right one. So the if statement didn't work.

**And here is another example:**

```
#define TEST_EQ_BASE(equality,expect,actual,format) \
    do {    \
        test_count++;   \
        if (equality){  \
            test_pass++;\
        }else{  \
            main_ret = 1;   \
            fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d: expect: " format " actual: " format "\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,expect,actual);\
        }   \
    }while (0)
```

In this code, the if statement works.

I am very confused about it, why is the difference?

Thank you!

**Edit:**

Sorry you guys, I am a junior student, not so familiar with the macro, so sorry.

I checked the result, the if statement did worked, but the compiler still complains:

```
uninitialized.h:88:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOG’
  LOG("__uninitialized_copy_aux: copying without constructor...",NULL,NULL);
  ^
stl_config.h:53:87: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 7 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
    fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d: %s, [%s] : %d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,operation,parameter,value);\
```

This is the output:

```
uninitialized.h:88: __uninitialized_copy_aux: copying without constructor...
```

This is the macro expanded:

```
do { if ((__null) == (__null))
{ fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d: %s, [%s] : %d\n","uninitialized.h",80,"__uninitialized_copy_aux: copying with constructor...",__null,__null); }else 
{ fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d: %s\n","uninitialized.h",80,"__uninitialized_copy_aux: copying with constructor..."); } } while(0);
```

So I think the problem is when passing NULL to the macro, the compiler gives the warning, can I eliminate the warning?

Thank you!!

Comment: First of all, don't create your own symbols with leading underscore followed by another underscore or by an upper-case letter, [those are reserved](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/440558). Secondly, have you tried running only the preprocessor to see what the macro invocation expands to?

Comment: `if ((parameter) == (NULL))`, your `parameter` is `NULL`, what is your problem?

Comment: Also please show us the *exact* warning the compiler gives you, verbatim, complete and unedited.

Comment: Anyway, type of `NULL` is unspecified, `%s` need a `char*` or `const char*`

Comment: Should the comparison not be `(parameter) != NULL`, anyway?

Comment: Please add the warning to the Q. However, as said by @Rene you have to negate the condition to make it semantically useful.

Comment: You should cast each parameter you pass to `fprintf` from a macro, since the compiler has no way to know what the parameter types are. (Or better yet, call your own function that has well-defined types rather than using `...`.)

Comment: You probably need to rethink the `#define` in your `#else` clause.  If you do not have `SHOW_LOGS_` defined, your invocation `LOG("ROUNDING UP...",NULL,NULL);` becomes `("ROUNDING UP...",NULL,NULL);` which is a parenthesized statement expression featuring the comma operator .  Often, you end up with `#define LOG(operation, parameter, value) ((void)0)`.  There are merits to evaluating the parameters — you'd probably want to use `#define LOG(operation, parameter, value) ((void)((operation), (parameter), (value)))` or thereabouts to ensure that the value is discarded.

Comment: See also [C `#define` macro for debug printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868).

Comment: an obvious solution is `LOG("ROUNDING UP...",NULL,0);`  . The last argument is printed with `%d` so it should have type `int`

Answer (score 2):

Please look at your code again.

```
#define LOG(operation, parameter, value) \
do { \
    if ((parameter) == (NULL)){ \
        fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d: %s, [%s] : %d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,operation,parameter,value);\
    }else { \
        fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d: %s\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,operation);\
    } \
} while(0)
```

Are you really going to `fprintf` the `parameter` if `(parameter) == (NULL)` ?

Try change this line

```
if ((parameter) == (NULL)){ \
```

to

```
if ((parameter)){ \
```