# How to manage debug mode of application in runtime?

Tags: c, linux, architecture, trace

Suppose we have application on Linux, pure C. Application consists of several functions - `f1`, `f2` and `f3`, which receive a structure. One element of the structure is `debug_mode`, with values `ON` or `OFF`.

How can I switch debug mode in `f1`, `f2` and `f3` (for example, some `printf`s) when the structure has `debug_mode == ON`?

Should I always use `if` statements to check `debug_mode` for every incoming structure or there is some another best practise to not use always `if` statements?

For example, these could be traces in telecom products, where we could collect some trace data for a specified subscriber.

Comment: If you want to check if a particular variable at run time has a given value, you use an `if` statement.

Comment: We have no way of knowing what you are talking about. This "debug mode" is your application specific feature.

Comment: I would suggest using a logging libary or special logging functions instead of `if (..) printf`

Comment: Consider [C `#define` macro for debug printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing).  The code outlined there supports 'debug levels', and associates printing with debug levels.  For larger programs, I use the 'multiple subsystem' code alluded to, with the ability to have different debug levels for separate subsystems at run time.  You can control whether debug is included at all; you can also control how much debug output is generated at runtime.

Comment: He wants to change it during runtime. Macros do not help here. A solution would be a global variable. This variable is altered by a signal handler and queried via `if (GLOBAL_DEBUG) printf`

Comment: And if you're curious, you can look at my code in GitHub in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack
Overflow Questions) repository as files `debug.c`, `debug.h` and `mddebug.c` in the
[src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq)
sub-directory.

Comment: Your question is unclear and too broad. You don't tell enough about your application! You should provide some [MCVE]. Please **edit your question** to improve it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can change it during runtime like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FALSE 0 
#define TRUE 1

volatile sig_atomic_t GLOBAL_DEBUG = FALSE;

void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGUSR1) {
        // printf("received SIGUSR1\n");
        GLOBAL_DEBUG = TRUE;
    } else if (signo == SIGUSR2) {
        GLOBAL_DEBUG = FALSE;
        // printf("received SIGUSR2\n");
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("\ncan't catch SIGUSR1\n");

    if (signal(SIGUSR2, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("\ncan't catch SIGUSR2\n");

    while (TRUE) {
        if (GLOBAL_DEBUG) printf ("DEBUG == TRUE\n");
        printf ("Hello world\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

And the switch GLOBAL_DEBUG during runtime like this :

```
user@host:~ $ kill -SIGUSR2 <pid of program>
user@host:~ $ kill -SIGUSR1 <pid of program>
```

BTW, read [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) (explaining why `printf` should be avoided inside signal handlers) and [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). [`sig_atomic_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/sig_atomic_t) is specified in the C11 standard (see [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)).

Comment: Using `printf` (which is not an *async-signal-safe* function) inside a signal handler is **against the rules** of [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) and [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). So it is *undefined behavior*; without these `printf ` the answer is interesting, so please edit your answer to remove these offending `printf`-s inside your `sig_handler`

Comment: Also `GLOBAL_DEBUG` should be declared `volatile sig_atomic_t GLOBAL_DEBUG;` not `int GLOBAL_DEBUG;`

Comment: This is just a demo.

Comment: So I edited your answer to improve it. The original was wrong

Answer (score 1):

You could use signals (see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) & [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)), as explained in [mbieren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48750484/841108). Of course you cannot call `printf` (or any non async-signal-safe function) from a signal handler, and the flag should [be declared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/sig_atomic_t) as `volatile sig_atomic_t GLOBAL_DEBUG;`

You could design your program otherwise. Perhaps your program has already some event loop (e.g. because it is a GUI application). Then you could add some RPCJSON service (or some HTTP one, or your own [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) or [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) based protocol, probably some [text-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_protocol) one) to your program. You'll find many libraries to help you (for example, [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) enables you to add some HTTP service to your program; so you might change the debug flag via your web server!).

You don't tell enough about your program to get more precise help.