# How to make a __VA_ARGS__ macro which can be called with no arguments?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have a macro:

```
#define debug(fmt, ...) printf("%lu %s:%s:%i " fmt, ms(), __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

which does just what I want.

I can call it with:

```
debug("i: %i\n", i);
```

to print the value of `i`.

My problem is that I can't call it with:

```
debug("got here");
```

as that expands to:

```
printf("%lu %s:%s:%i %s " "got here", ms(), __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__,)
```

which is a trailing-comma bug.

How can I change my `__VA_ARGS__` macro so that it can handle the "no variables"/"only format string" case?

Comment: GCC has an extension for this. Try `,##__VA_ARGS__` instead of `, __VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: See [`#define` macro for debug printing in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1644868/15168)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two steps:

```
#define debug(...) DEBUG(__VA_ARGS__, "")
#define DEBUG(fmt, ...) printf("%lu %s:%s:%i " fmt "%s", ms(), __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)

debug("%d\n", 42);
debug("Hello\n");
```

In this way, even if you don't pass a second param it is replaced by an `""`  and results in a NOP.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to concatenate string literals in the macro itself, you can split the `printf` into two parts: One for the statistics, the other for your debug message. Yoke them together with the old `do { ... } while (0)` macro trick.

```
#define debug(...) do {                                                 \
        printf("%lu %s:%s:%i ", ms(), __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__);    \
        printf(__VA_ARGS__);                                            \
    } while (0)
```

Then you don't need the `fmt` as separate argument and can just pass `__VA_ARGS__` to the second `printf`.

Comment: In a multi-threaded program, this opens up the possibility of two threads interfering with each other — whereas a single call to `printf()` ensures that does not happen. POSIX provides [`flockfile()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html) and `funlockfile()` to allow grouping of separate operations — so adding `flockfile(stdout);` before the first `printf()` and `funlockfile()` after the second would ensure that other threads do not split the message.