# Remove debug strings from release build

Tags: c, string, release

I am trying to find the best way to exclude my debug strings from making it to my release build. Currently, I'm outputting debug strings via syslog, and I have the current setup in my `debug.c` file:

```c
#ifdef DEBUG
void init_debug(void)
{
    openlog("MyAppName", LOG_PERROR, LOG_SYSLOG);
}
#else
void init_debug(void){}
#endif

#ifdef DEBUG
void debug(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vsyslog(LOG_DEBUG, format, args);
    va_end(args);
}
#else
void debug(const char* format, ...){}
#endif
```

So, you can see that the functions will be empty when I build the release version. However, when I call the function, I would do something like:

```c
#include "debug.h"

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    init_debug();
    debug("Number of arguments: %d", argc);
}
```

However, this of course makes my strings appear in the release build as they're still htere. The easy solution is to do something like:

```c
#include "debug.h"

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    init_debug();
#ifdef DEBUG
   debug("Number of arguments: %d", argc);
#endif
}
```

But that's incredibly verbose, and hard to read (especially when it's grouped up with real code).

Are there other, more elegant solutions?

Comment: What happens if you replace the empty debug functions with just empty preprocessor "functions" `#define debug(...)` ? (That's actually dangerous if you ever have side-effects in the parameters you pass to debug)

Comment: Consider the techniques described in [`#define` macro for debug printing in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1644868/15168). You'd need to adapt them a little, but the emphasis would be on 'a little'.  You hide the conditional code (`#ifdef DEBUG` / `#else` / `#endif`) inside the header.  You invoke the functions unconditionally in the source, but the header controls whether they expand to operational code or not.

Comment: Maybe `#define NDEBUG` / `#include <assert.h>` ... `assert((argc == 3) && "wrong number of arguments");` or similar

Comment: @Mat: debug code should be read-only code with no side-effects, precisely so that there is no problem if the code is removed.  If the debugging code modifies what it operates on, it is no longer just debugging code.

Comment: @Mat that perfectly worked! If you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Note the caveats documented in the "`#define` macro for debug printing in C" question before going with the 'empty preprocessor macros for non-debug builds'.  Specifically, be aware that debug code easily gets out of sync with the surrounding code unless it is compiled frequently.